# Why would OpenVPN attempt a TCP connection in a UDP setup?

Tags: openvpn

I connect to an OpenVPN server (`IP_of_OpenVPN_server`) from a network which is behind a firewall (iptables managed by Shorewall). The firewall is set up to only allow outbound OpenVPN (`udp/1194`) traffic.

The setup works correctly: when the OpenVPN tunnel is shut down no connection go through, it is back when the tunnel is restored.

**My problem is that I intermittently log rejected TCP `SYN` attempts to the OpenVPN server, even though the connection is configured for UDP**
What kind of TCP connection is OpenVPN attempting with this remote server? (this is the only service aware of `IP_of_OpenVPN_server`)

Logs of the rejected connections:

```
Apr 30 17:11:02 srv kernel: [ 5409.732525] Shorewall:vpn-int:REJECT:IN=br1 OUT=int0 MAC=fe:a8:fa:bd:39:3f:00:16:3e:7b:86:db:08:00 SRC=10.10.11.1 DST=IP_of_OpenVPN_server LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=50338 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40160 DPT=51413 WINDOW=7300 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Apr 30 17:11:31 srv kernel: [ 5439.043955] Shorewall:vpn-int:REJECT:IN=br1 OUT=int0 MAC=fe:a8:fa:bd:39:3f:00:16:3e:7b:86:db:08:00 SRC=10.10.11.1 DST=IP_of_OpenVPN_server LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=71 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53301 DPT=51969 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Apr 30 17:11:47 srv kernel: [ 5455.068855] Shorewall:vpn-int:REJECT:IN=br1 OUT=int0 MAC=fe:a8:fa:bd:39:3f:00:16:3e:7b:86:db:08:00 SRC=10.10.11.1 DST=IP_of_OpenVPN_server LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=33225 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55281 DPT=51969 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

OpenVPN Configuration

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote IP_of_OpenVPN_server 1194
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0
remote-cert-tls server
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
pull
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(...)
```

Comment: Why do you assume those TCP sync packets belongs to OpenVPN process? Use netstat -p to verify it. This: "the only service aware of IP_of_OpenVPN_server" is not an explanation.

Comment: @MichalSokolowski: this is  a container with no other network-enabled services running. When OpenVPN is down there is no traffic (neither UDP nor TCP). When it is up the expected UDP traffic is there, together with the unexpected TCP one. Moreover, the dest IP is the one of the OpenVPN server, of which nobody else beside the OpenVPN client knows about.

Comment: All I can tell you is that, I've never seen such traffic even now having more than 200 connected clients, take a look please: http://pastebin.com/120PWmLB . It's Debian 7 ARM client. IHMO the assumption that those packets belongs to OpenVPN's client process is wrong.

Comment: Config file: http://pastebin.com/wQiXiWdP